# Thinkpad T450s WWAN M.2 slot - M or B key?

Tags: laptop, thinkpad, m.2

My Thinkpad T450s has an unpopulated M.2 slot that can be used to install a WWAN card. As far as I can tell, it's an M-keyed slot - the tab that divides pins is on the left, and the shorter section has five contacts:
[image]

But [the manufacturer's manual](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_T450s/ThinkPad_T450s_Spec.PDF) states that the following WWAN cards are compatible with the laptop:

- [Ericsson N5321](https://notebooks-trade.de/media/image/79/92/18/UMTSModem04W3842-3823_1280x1280.jpg)
- [Sierra Wireless EM7345](https://www.lapstore.de/sd.php?shop=lapstore&d=31159&s=C)

both of which would seem to be B-keyed - they have six contacts and there's even a "B" marking above the contacts - the Ericsson for example:

[image]

So is my laptop's M.2 slot B-keyed after all? How come the number of contacts on the card and the number of pins in the slot don't match?

Comment: You realize you already have a wireless card, that’s in use, and the new card would require another antenna to function which your device doesn’t have.

Comment: @Ramhound: I think that's normal; doesn't WWAN (as in LTE/4G, not as in WLAN/Wi-Fi) use a separate set of antennas anyway, i.e. the red & blue cables in the photo?

Comment: Lenovo is very good at specifying compatible cards for their machines, and in my experience they almost always work, so I am not sure I understand the concern.

Comment: I didn’t see those cables. If the manual says the card is compatible then it’s compatible

Comment: I'm not concerned it won't work, but I thought the type of slot (M vs B) can be easily determined by just counting the contacts, which doesn't seem to be the case here (as I thought it was an M slot, but Lenovo says it's for a B card) - so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: In the socket, you're looking at the "pins" that will connect to the back of the card. The photo is of the front of the card.